# Нужно избавиться от Stackoverflow

Tags: java, рекурсия

Код:

```
public static boolean maMaleRozdiely(int[] p, int odIdx, int poIdx, int rozdiel) {
        if ((poIdx-odIdx) == 0) return true;
        if (Math.abs(p[odIdx + 1] - p[odIdx]) > rozdiel)
            return false;
        
        return maMaleRozdiely(p, odIdx+1, poIdx, rozdiel);
    }
```

нужно сделать так что при входном массиве 10000000 не выписывало ошибку

Comment: уберите рекурсию из функции и будет вам счастье

Comment: @ArchDemon, суть в том что нужно с рекурсией сделать

Comment: Как вариант увеличить размер стека. Или изменять логику, чтобы не было столько вызовов. Я правильно понимаю, что макс. кол-во вызовов 10000000?

Comment: @afjord задание такое что ничего не надо менять, нужно в коде изменить что-то что бы не было ошибки, к примеру поделить массив на 2 части пройти первую часть потом другую, но как это реализовать....

Answer (score 0):

Крайне рекомендую Вам переписать код без рекурсии. Вы можете увеличичить размер стека указав параметр `Xss`. Предполагаю на разных версиях максимальный размер стека может быть разный, но на сколько помню вроде он равен `1g`.

Накидал небольшой пример для замера максимальной глубины рекурсии:

```
package com.somepackage;

public class Main {
    private static int recurse(int i) {
        try {
            return recurse(i + 1);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            return i;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = recurse(0);
        System.out.print(
                "Recursion depth is " + i + ".");
    }
}
```

Без указанного значения размера стека получаем следующие значения:

```
Recursion depth is 20155.
```

При запуске с заданным значением размера стека `1g`:

```
Recursion depth is 44707800.
```

Пример запуска:

```
java -Xss1g com.somepackage.Main
```